# PANDAS: Split list into rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 lists id_list version_list and phases_list which i extracted using methods. 
My code is

```
a = pd.DataFrame(id_list, columns = ['ID'])
b = pd.DataFrame(version_list, columns = ['Version'])
c = pd.DataFrame(phases_list, columns = ['Required'])

x = pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=1, sort=False)
df2 = x.to_excel('df2.xlsx')
```

The output is

```
  id     version  required  
0 X Y Z  1 2 3    tur mir tur
```

But i want it like this

```
  id      version     required
0 X        1           tur
1 Y        2           mir
2 Z        3           tur
```

How can I do this in Pandas?

Also one more issue is I extracted the data with Index Values so list is somewhat like 6 X 17 Y 20 Z also with version and required columns all have index values, how can i remove the index number from the list?

So now the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# stack your frame, split on your separator, reset_index and transpose
df.stack().str.split(' ', expand=True).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).T

    id version required
0    X       1      tur
1    Y       2      mir
2    Z       3      tur
```

Comment: It returns me this error. 'list' object has no attribute 'stack' Have I placed the code wrong or done it wrong?. I don't know what to replace instead of df i replaced it with id_list

Comment: df is the dataframe, in your example it is `x`

Comment: can you please help me for this question which is quite similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61519995/pandas-removing-index-values-and-splitting-in-excel-the-value-in-one-cell-to-di

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably the constructor using a dict:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': id_list, 'Version': version_list, 'Required': phases_list})
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an alternative - i love @Yo_Chris's solution though :

```
m = zip(*[v.array[0].split() for k,v in df.items()])
pd.DataFrame(m).set_axis(df.columns,axis=1)

    id  version required
0   X   1   tur
1   Y   2   mir
2   Z   3   tur
```