# PANDAS: Removing Index Values and Splitting in Excel the value in one cell to different rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have written this code to extract data from one excel file and again prepare another excel file with extracted ID, Version, Phase. It extracts it but places in excel wrongly. It places the values with Index and also it put in excel all ID's in one Cell all Versions in one cell So i want it to be in different rows below the Id column
Here is my code
[Input File Link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZrUbftMppFf8L3jgWl2i8bsgUavOHnkZ/view?usp=sharing) [Output File Link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BoUiICzRgkX3AN9OcRIEDnh9c3qKNL3l/view?usp=sharing)

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['ID']
vals = ['Version']
phas = ['Phase']
id_index_list = []
id_list = []
verindex_list = []
version_list = []
phaseindex_list = []
phases_list = []
tolist = []
df_pver = pd.read_excel('pver.xlsm', 'PVP', header = None)

#Name of Project
dz= df_pver.iloc[[0],[0]]

#Finding ID
dy= df_pver.xs(0)

for id in dy:
    if 'ID' in str(id):
        #ID list Finding location of Column where ID exists
        zr= dy[dy==id].index.values
        for item in zr:
            if not item in id_index_list:
                id_index_list.append(item)
        mylist = [df_pver.xs(0)[id_index_list]]
        #finding the location of ID and moving 3 column aside to find the Version
        ze= dy[dy==id].index.values + 3
        for item in ze:
            if not item in verindex_list:
                verindex_list.append(item)
        mylist2 = [df_pver.xs(0)[verindex_list]]
        #findind the phase the project is in
        zp= dy[dy==id].index.values + 1
        for item in zp:
            if not item in phaseindex_list:
                phaseindex_list.append(item)
        mylist3 = [df_pver.xs(1)[phaseindex_list]]


id_list.append(mylist)
version_list.append(mylist2)
phases_list.append(mylist3)

a = pd.DataFrame(id_list, columns = cols)
b = pd.DataFrame(version_list, columns = vals)
c = pd.DataFrame(phases_list, columns = phas)



x = pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=1, sort=False)
x.stack().str.split(' ', expand=True).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).T
x.to_excel("df2.xlsx", index=False)
```

This Code is finding the data which I need but giving output falsely.

The output in excel is

```
   id                  version                     required  
0  17 X 18 Y 22 Z     20 1  21 2 24 3            18 gantt 19 Pie 23 ipex
```

**But i want it like this without the index also splitted into different rows instead of all in one cell.**

```
  id      version     required
0 X        1           gantt
1 Y        2           Pie
2 Z        3           ipex
```

Can Someone please help with this

Comment: just add index=False to the to_excel function to get ridd of the index

Comment: I tried index=False but still it gives output with index values.I think in the step where i am trying to extract data, the list is embedded with Index Values, I don't know there if I should put index=False. Can I put somewhere in mylist to remove Index?

Comment: There is way to much obsfucation in your code, can you add sample input and output then we can help you

Comment: Hi Datanovice here re links to data Thanks [Input File Link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZrUbftMppFf8L3jgWl2i8bsgUavOHnkZ/view?usp=sharing) [Output File Link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BoUiICzRgkX3AN9OcRIEDnh9c3qKNL3l/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your columns are already in order of id, phase and version. Also index 3 did not have a number after `ID:`

```
# read excel
df = pd.read_excel('pver.xlsx')
# find the columns that start with ID, transpose, reset the index and split on colon
ids = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('ID')]].T.reset_index()['index'].str.split(':.|:', expand=True)[1].to_numpy()
# find the columns that start with QA and transpose
phase = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('QA')]].T[0].to_numpy()
# find the columns that start with V or OEM, and transpose
v = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('V') | df.columns.str.startswith('OEM SW')]].T.index
# vstack and to pd.dataFrame
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([ids,v,phase])).T
# name columns
new_df.columns = ['ID', 'Version', 'Phase']

           ID        Version               Phase
0     1907839           V100  during development
1    01907820           V110  during development
2   189634226           V120  during development
3                       V130  during development
4           1           V200       Raw Container
5           2           V220                 NaN
6           3    OEM SW name                 NaN
7           4  OEM SW name.1                 NaN
8           5  OEM SW name.2                 NaN
9           6  OEM SW name.3                 NaN
10          7  OEM SW name.4                 NaN
11          8  OEM SW name.5                 NaN
12          9  OEM SW name.6                 NaN
13         10  OEM SW name.7                 NaN
14         11  OEM SW name.8                 NaN
15         12  OEM SW name.9                 NaN
```

Comment: Wow! I am totally amazed how simple the code could be. Thanks a lot its going to be of great help.